# Слишком много файлов в каталоге

Tags: linux

При выполнении поиска похожих изображений с помощью команды

```
findimagedupes -t 85 Папка_1 Папка_2
```

выскакивает ошибка:

> findimagedupes: Argument list too long

Как решить эту пролему?

Comment: Сравнивать файлы не все сразу а кусками. Получить список всех фалов, разбить его на 3 части, прогнать через findimagedupes 1 и 2, 1 и 3, 2 и 3 части списка, при увеличении количества файлов увеличить количество частей. С командой помочь не могу.

Comment: Никогда не пользовался, но судя по строке  `If a file "-" is given, a list of files is read from stdin.` в http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/findimagedupes.1p.html можно попробовать `ls -d  Папка_1/* Папка_2/* | findimagedupes -t 85 -`  (-  вместо списка файлов означает, что имена файлов надо брать из stdin)

Answer (score 2):

согласно [`man findimagedupes`](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/manpage.html), программа умеет вести базу данных с «отпечатками» (*fingerprints*) изображений (и, конечно, именами файлов, в которых изображения хранятся).

указать файл базы данных можно с помощью опции `-f файл`. если он не существует, то будет создан. для общей информации: база данных — в формате [berkeley db](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB).

если указана база данных, поиск дубликатов будет производиться и в ней тоже, а сигнатуры всех файлов, переданных аргументами (точнее, изображений, хранящихся в этих файлах), будут добавлены в базу данных.

несколько баз данных можно слить в одну (в этом случае опцию `-f файл` можно использовать многократно) с помощью опции `-M файл`:

```
$ findimagedupes -n -M /путь/к/объединённой.бд -f /путь/к/первой.бд -f /путь/ко/второй.бд
```

есть ещё несколько опций для манипуляций с базой данных. см. *man*-страницу.

---

собственно о проблеме:

1. файлы (с отпечатками) можно добавлять в базу данных последовательно:

   ```
   $ findimagedupes -f /путь/к/бд -R -n /путь/к/первому/каталогу
   $ findimagedupes -f /путь/к/бд -R -n /путь/ко/второму/каталогу
   ...
   $ findimagedupes -f /путь/к/бд
   ```

   опция `-n` — не искать дубликаты (только подсчёт отпечатков и сохранение в бд), опция `-R` — просматривать каталоги рекурсивно.
2. если файлов в одном каталоге очень много и возникает упомянутая ошибка, можно выбирать файлы «пачками»: `/путь/к/[a-f]*` — файлы, начинающиеся с `a, b, … f`.
3. если предыдущий вариант не подходит, можно вызывать программу, используя связку `find`+`xargs`. эта связка подставит максимально возможное количество файлов, запуская требующуюся программу несколько раз (если потребуется):

   ```
   $ find /путь/к/каталогу -type f | xargs findimagedupes -f /путь/к/бд
   ```